# Applying an ellipsis to multiline text

Tags: html, css, ellipsis

Is there a solution to add ellipsis on last line inside a div with a fluid height (20%)?

I found the `-webkit-line-clamp` function in CSS, but in my case the line number will be depending on window size.

```css
p {
    width:100%;
    height:20%;
    background:red;
    position:absolute;
}
```

```html
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla sed dui felis. Vivamus vitae pharetra nisl, eget fringilla elit. Ut nec est sapien. Aliquam dignissim velit sed nunc imperdiet cursus. Proin arcu diam, tempus ac vehicula a, dictum quis nibh. Maecenas vitae quam ac mi venenatis vulputate. Suspendisse fermentum suscipit eros, ac ultricies leo sagittis quis. Nunc sollicitudin lorem eget eros eleifend facilisis. Quisque bibendum sem at bibendum suscipit. Nam id tellus mi. Mauris vestibulum, eros ac ultrices lacinia, justo est faucibus ipsum, sed sollicitudin sapien odio sed est. In massa ipsum, bibendum quis lorem et, volutpat ultricies nisi. Maecenas scelerisque sodales ipsum a hendreritLorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla sed dui felis. Vivamus vitae pharetra nisl, eget fringilla elit. Ut nec est sapien. Aliquam dignissim velit sed nunc imperdiet cursus. Proin arcu diam, tempus ac vehicula a, dictum quis nibh. Maecenas vitae quam ac mi venenatis vulputate. Suspendisse fermentum suscipit eros, ac ultricies leo sagittis quis. Nunc sollicitudin lorem eget eros eleifend facilisis. Quisque bibendum sem at bibendum suscipit. Nam id tellus mi. Mauris vestibulum, eros ac ultrices lacinia, justo est faucibus ipsum, sed sollicitudin sapien odio sed est. In massa ipsum, bibendum quis lorem et, volutpat ultricies nisi. Maecenas scelerisque sodales ipsum a hendrerit.</p>
```

I have this JSFiddle to illustrate the issue. 
https://jsfiddle.net/96knodm6/

Comment: Your solution doesn't works for fluid height as we don't know exactly the number of lines depending on screen sizes. The only solution I found is to add a blurry div at the bottom to middle hide the last line.

Comment: [Live example of multiline text truncate](https://codepen.io/vsync/pen/poegrqa)

Comment: Note[,](https://semicolon.dev/stackoverflow/question/17/how-to-add-vertical-ellipsis-on-2nd-or-3rd-text-line-with-display-webkit-box-and-line-clamp) that it works only when `-webkit-box` is enabled on `display` property. It's an old property for flexbox, but it's a requirement for clamping, which can also be done with just `line-clamp` (without webkit prefix) on modern browsers.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I finally found a solution to do what I want. 
As `p` a paragraphe and `article` the wrapper. 
If you want to apply ellipsis to `p` depending on `article` height (which also depends on window height), you need to get the `height` of the `article`, the `line-height` of the `p` and then `articleHeight/lineHeight` to find the number of `line-clamp` that can be added dynamically then.

The only thing is the `line-height` should be declared in the css file.

Check the following code. If you change the height of the window, the `line-clamp` will change. Can be great to create a plug-in aiming to do that.

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/brunolandowski/hcecsnjL/)

```js
function lineclamp() {
  var lineheight = parseFloat($('p').css('line-height'));
  var articleheight = $('article').height(); 
  var calc = parseInt(articleheight/lineheight);
  $("p").css({"-webkit-line-clamp": "" + calc + ""});
}


$(document).ready(function() {
    lineclamp();
});

$( window ).resize(function() {
  lineclamp();
});
```

```css
article {
  height:60%;
  background:red;
  position:absolute;
}

p {
  margin:0;
  line-height:120%;
  display: -webkit-box;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<article>
 <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque lorem ligula, lacinia a justo sed, porttitor vulputate risus. In non feugiat risus. Sed vitae urna nisl. Duis suscipit volutpat sollicitudin. Donec ac massa elementum massa condimentum mollis. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Nulla sollicitudin sapien at enim sodales dapibus. Pellentesque sed nisl eu sem aliquam tempus nec ut leo. Quisque rutrum nulla nec aliquam placerat. Fusce a massa ut sem egestas imperdiet. Sed sollicitudin id dolor egestas malesuada. Quisque placerat lobortis ante, id ultrices ipsum hendrerit nec. Quisque quis ultrices erat.Nulla gravida ipsum nec sapien pellentesque pharetra. Suspendisse egestas aliquam nunc vel egestas. Nullam scelerisque purus interdum lectus consectetur mattis. Aliquam nunc erat, accumsan ut posuere eu, vehicula consequat ipsum. Fusce vel ex quis sem tristique imperdiet vel in mi. Cras leo orci, fermentum vitae volutpat vitae, convallis semper libero. Phasellus a volutpat diam. Ut pulvinar purus felis, eu vehicula enim aliquet vitae. Suspendisse quis lorem facilisis ante interdum euismod et vitae risus. Vestibulum varius nulla et enim malesuada fringilla. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque lorem ligula, lacinia a justo sed, porttitor vulputate risus. In non feugiat risus. Sed vitae urna nisl. Duis suscipit volutpat sollicitudin. Donec ac massa elementum massa condimentum mollis. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Nulla sollicitudin sapien at enim sodales dapibus. Pellentesque sed nisl eu sem aliquam tempus nec ut leo. Quisque rutrum nulla nec aliquam placerat. Fusce a massa ut sem egestas imperdiet. Sed sollicitudin id dolor egestas malesuada. Quisque placerat lobortis ante, id ultrices ipsum hendrerit nec.</p></article>
```

Comment: This answer is old, outdated, and therefore obselet.  See the above higher score answers that suggest the use of `-webkit-line-clamp`.

Comment: line-clamp only works if you know the amount of lines.

Answer (score 419):

Increase the ***-webkit-line-clamp: 4;***  to increase the number of lines:

```css
p {
    display: -webkit-box;
    max-width: 200px;
    -webkit-line-clamp: 4;
    -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, novum menandri adversarium ad vim, ad his persius nostrud conclusionemque. Ne qui atomorum pericula honestatis. Te usu quaeque detracto, idque nulla pro ne, ponderum invidunt eu duo. Vel velit tincidunt in, nulla bonorum id eam, vix ad fastidii consequat definitionem.</p>
```

---

Line clamp is a proprietary and undocumented CSS (webkit) : https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-line-clamp, so it currently works on only a few browsers.

Removed duplicated 'display' property + removed unnecessary 'text-overflow: ellipsis'.

Comment: Works well in Chrome, but not in Internet Explorer

Comment: now supported in firefox https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=WebKit-line-clamp

Comment: 95% is not «few». It's supported by Chromium, Safari, Webkit, Edge and others. It's only not supported by IE and Opera Mini.

Comment: `display: block; text-overflow: ellipsis;` are redundant here

Comment: wow!! I'm already styling web pages for 8 years & I never saw this line-clamp situation. I just wish the browsers would support this without prefixes

Comment: unfortunately, it's not cross-browser supported.

Comment: Whilst I don't care too much for older browsers and I'll probably just use this answer, its criminal that no-one has mentioned the top npm module for line clamping - https://www.npmjs.com/package/shave - I've never used it so can't comment on how well it works (or not) - but if docs are anything to go on it looks good - also ... worth adding a CSS max-height in case the browser does not support this to prevent your layout from breaking up

Comment: This is running for me in Chrome 93.0, Firefox 91 and Safari 14.1

Comment: FYI this wasn't working for me because the parent `<div>` was `display: flex`. I added another `<div>` surrounding my `<span>` which is `display: block` by default and then it worked

Comment: FYI when using `text-align: justify` the ellipsis is placed in the wrong location in Safari. Works fine in Chrome and Firefox.

Comment: It would be a great answer. But it would have high CLS. It should be reversed. Firstly hide with css and then show element

Comment: with `word-break: break-word;` works perfectly.

Comment: For anyone interested, the caniuse reference for -webkit-line-clamp and -webkit-box: https://caniuse.com/?search=line-clamp

Comment: For my case I needed to remove the overflow: hidden to make it works

Answer (score 196):

If you want to apply ellipsis (...) to a *single line of text*, CSS makes that somewhat easy with the [`text-overflow`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-overflow) property. It's still a bit tricky (due to all the requirements – see below), but `text-overflow` makes it possible and reliable.

If, however, you want to use ellipsis on *multiline text* – as would be the case here – then don't expect to have any fun. CSS has no standard method for doing this, and the workarounds are hit and miss.

#### Ellipsis for Single Line Text

With `text-overflow`, ellipsis can be applied to a single line of text. The following CSS requirements must be met:

- must have a `width`, `max-width` or `flex-basis`
- must have `white-space: nowrap`
- must have `overflow` with value other than `visible`
- must be `display: block` or `inline-block`
  (or the functional equivalent, such as a flex item).

So this will work:

```css
p {
  width: 200px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: inline-block;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<p>
  This is a test of CSS <i>text-overflow: ellipsis</i>. 
  This is a test of CSS <i>text-overflow: ellipsis</i>. 
  This is a test of CSS <i>text-overflow: ellipsis</i>. 
  This is a test of CSS <i>text-overflow: ellipsis</i>.
  This is a test of CSS <i>text-overflow: ellipsis</i>.
  This is a test of CSS <i>text-overflow: ellipsis</i>.
</p>
```

[jsFiddle version](http://jsfiddle.net/9t2w7yex/)

BUT, try removing the `width`, or letting the `overflow` default to `visible`, or removing `white-space: nowrap`, or using something other than a block container element, AND, ellipsis fails miserably.

One big takeaway here: *`text-overflow: ellipsis` has no effect on multiline text*. (The `white-space: nowrap` requirement alone eliminates that possibility.)

```css
p {
    width: 200px;
    /* white-space: nowrap; */
    height: 90px; /* new */
    overflow: hidden;
    display: inline-block;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
    margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<p>
  This is a test of CSS <i>text-overflow: ellipsis</i>. 
  This is a test of CSS <i>text-overflow: ellipsis</i>. 
  This is a test of CSS <i>text-overflow: ellipsis</i>. 
  This is a test of CSS <i>text-overflow: ellipsis</i>.
  This is a test of CSS <i>text-overflow: ellipsis</i>.
  This is a test of CSS <i>text-overflow: ellipsis</i>.
</p>
```

[jsFiddle version](http://jsfiddle.net/9t2w7yex/1/)

---

#### Ellipsis for Multiline Text

Because CSS has no property for ellipsis on multiline text, various workarounds have been created. Several of these methods can be found here:

- [jQuery dotdotdot...](http://dotdotdot.frebsite.nl/)
- [Line Clampin’ (Truncating Multiple Line Text)](https://css-tricks.com/line-clampin/)
- [CSS Ellipsis: How to Manage Multi-Line Ellipsis in Pure CSS](https://web.archive.org/web/20160506153100/http://www.mobify.com/blog/multiline-ellipsis-in-pure-css/)
- [A pure CSS solution for multiline text truncation](http://hackingui.com/front-end/a-pure-css-solution-for-multiline-text-truncation/)

The Mobify link above was removed and now references an archive.org copy, but appears to be implemented in [this codepen](https://codepen.io/abothun/pen/MKpPjX).

Comment: Another method by [Natalia Onischuk](http://hackingui.com/front-end/a-pure-css-solution-for-multiline-text-truncation/).

Comment: 7kb for a jQuery plugin when all the user wants is ... added to their text?? Seriously, seems like someone needs to learn to design plugins to be more efficient.

Comment: @AndroidDev You need to know where to cut the text. Measuring text and clipping regions is not simple. Try to measure only the last line of a wrapped block of text. You can't do it easily. One technique is to append a 0-width inline element onto the end of the paragraph and get that element's x position. That's still not even precise, because there is space between the last character and the 0-width element. On top of that these plugins support multiple browsers, where the techniques to measure the text and boundaries are different. This isn't as simple as just adding "..." to the text.

Comment: Lodash also has a very nice [truncate](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.5#truncate) method that will add ellipsis to multi-line text.

Comment: As of this writing the CSS Ellipsis link is to a page that offers a zip file DL that 404s

Comment: Don't worry I never expect to have fun with CSS I don't need the warning

Comment: As of 2020 - this is not the best answer anymore. The -webkit-line-clamp (answer by Jobincs) is now fully supported on all major browsers (including Chrome, Firefox, Safari, Edge, and more...) and is much easier and better solution, with no need for external library or special tweaks.

Answer (score 67):

[**Demo**](https://javascript-html-5.blogspot.com/)

```css
p {
    width:100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    display: -webkit-box;
    -webkit-line-clamp: 2;
    -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
    background:#fff;
}
```

```html
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla sed dui felis. Vivamus vitae pharetra nisl, eget fringilla elit. Ut nec est sapien. Aliquam dignissim velit sed nunc imperdiet cursus. Proin arcu diam, tempus ac vehicula a, dictum quis nibh. Maecenas vitae quam ac mi venenatis vulputate. Suspendisse fermentum suscipit eros, ac ultricies leo sagittis quis. Nunc sollicitudin lorem eget eros eleifend facilisis. Quisque bibendum sem at bibendum suscipit. Nam id tellus mi. Mauris vestibulum, eros ac ultrices lacinia, justo est faucibus ipsum, sed sollicitudin sapien odio sed est. In massa ipsum, bibendum quis lorem et, volutpat ultricies nisi. Maecenas scelerisque sodales ipsum a hendreritLorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla sed dui felis. Vivamus vitae pharetra nisl, eget fringilla elit. Ut nec est sapien. Aliquam dignissim velit sed nunc imperdiet cursus. Proin arcu diam, tempus ac vehicula a, dictum quis nibh. Maecenas vitae quam ac mi venenatis vulputate. Suspendisse fermentum suscipit eros, ac ultricies leo sagittis quis. Nunc sollicitudin lorem eget eros eleifend facilisis. Quisque bibendum sem at bibendum suscipit. Nam id tellus mi. Mauris vestibulum, eros ac ultrices lacinia, justo est faucibus ipsum, sed sollicitudin sapien odio sed est. In massa ipsum, bibendum quis lorem et, volutpat ultricies nisi. Maecenas scelerisque sodales ipsum a hendrerit.</p>
```

Comment: `position:absolute;` is redundant here

Comment: This looks like an obscure solution that I would expect to work on very few browsers, but is actually [supported almost everywhere](https://caniuse.com/css-line-clamp) and even made it into [CSS working draft](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-overflow-3/#webkit-line-clamp). Currently the best answer I'd say

Comment: `width: 100%;` also is redundant here

Comment: Agreed, this would be perfect and probably accepted without the width:100%; background of course also has no relevancy here but is useful to visualise.

Comment: Using concepts from this answer allowed me to get a better result than from any of the other options. Thank you!

Answer (score 43):

I took a look at how YouTube solves it on their homepage and simplified it:

```
.multine-ellipsis {
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  display: -webkit-box;
  -webkit-line-clamp: 2;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: normal;
}
```

This will allow 2 lines of code and then append an ellipsis.

Gist: https://gist.github.com/eddybrando/386d3350c0b794ea87a2082bf4ab014b

Comment: nice one, but a future one (for FF and IE) it seems https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-line-clamp

Comment: Here in 2023, this solution appears to work in FF, Chrome, Safari. And I would assume Edge since it's a Chromium Browser.

Answer (score 42):

Please check this css for ellipsis to multi-line text

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 50px;
}

/* mixin for multiline */
.block-with-text {
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  line-height: 1.2em;
  max-height: 6em;
  text-align: justify;
  margin-right: -1em;
  padding-right: 1em;
}
.block-with-text:before {
  content: '...';
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}
.block-with-text:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  width: 1em;
  height: 1em;
  margin-top: 0.2em;
  background: white;
}
```

```html
<p class="block-with-text">The Hitch Hiker's Guide to the Galaxy has a few things to say on the subject of towels. A towel, it says, is about the most massivelyuseful thing an interstellar hitch hiker can have. Partly it has great practical value - you can wrap it around you for warmth as you bound across the cold moons of  Jaglan Beta; you can lie on it on the brilliant marble-sanded beaches of Santraginus V, inhaling the heady sea vapours; you can sleep under it beneath the stars which shine so redly on the desert world of Kakrafoon;  use it to sail a mini raft down the slow heavy river Moth; wet it for use in hand-to-hand-combat; wrap it round your head to ward off noxious fumes or to avoid the gaze of the Ravenous Bugblatter Beast of Traal (a mindboggingly stupid animal, it assumes that if you can't see it, it can't see you - daft as a bush, but very ravenous); you can wave your towel in emergencies as a distress signal, and of course dry yourself off with it if it still seems to be clean enough. More importantly, a towel has immense psychological value. For some reason, if a strag (strag: non-hitch hiker) discovers that a hitch hiker has his towel with him, he will automatically assume that he is also in possession of a toothbrush, face flannel, soap, tin of biscuits, flask, compass, map, ball of string, gnat spray, wet weather gear, space suit etc., etc. Furthermore, the strag will then happily lend the hitch hiker any of these or a dozen other items that the hitch hiker might accidentally have "lost". What the strag will think is that any man who can hitch the length and breadth of the galaxy, rough it, slum it, struggle against terrible odds, win through, and still knows where his towel is is clearly a man to be reckoned with.</p>
```

Comment: I love this solution. Just an extra tweak to :before `right: 1em; background-color: white;` so that the ellipsis stays inside the box.

Comment: Source : http://hackingui.com/front-end/a-pure-css-solution-for-multiline-text-truncation/

Comment: that will work, but you need to check if text is overflowing container with javascript. Otherwise those 3 dots will be there even if your text doesn't exceeds container

Comment: Every time you implement this solution, a designer collapses. The dots outside of the container is just a no go

Comment: Also note the caveat: "We need to have a plain background color for covering up the ‘…’ if the text is less than the max number of lines," ([Natalia Onischuk](http://hackingui.com/front-end/a-pure-css-solution-for-multiline-text-truncation/)).

Comment: @Hamid it seems that what you suggest works nicely when there is an overflow, but creates "..." also when there's no overflow, isn't it? Have a look: https://jsfiddle.net/c6axmsfv/

Comment: ellipsis is not inline three dots, it is ellipsis and is one character, so better to use this: …

Comment: This works thanks! Only in my case I need to add line height to ... so that it aligned with text.

Answer (score 9):

I have just been playing around a little bit with this concept. Basically, if you are ok with potentially having a pixel or so cut off from your last character, here is a pure css and html solution:

The way this works is by absolutely positioning a div below the viewable region of a viewport. We want the div to offset up into the visible region as our content grows. If the content grows too much, our div will offset too high, so upper bound the height our content can grow.

HTML:

```
<div class="text-container">
  <span class="text-content">
    PUT YOUR TEXT HERE
    <div class="ellipsis">...</div> // You could even make this a pseudo-element
  </span>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.text-container {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    color: #838485;
    width: 24em;
    height: calc(2em + 5px); // This is the max height you want to show of the text. A little extra space is for characters that extend below the line like 'j'
    overflow: hidden;
    white-space: normal;
}

.text-content {
  word-break: break-all;
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  max-height: 3em;       // This prevents the ellipsis element from being offset too much. It should be 1 line height greater than the viewport 
}

.ellipsis {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: calc(4em + 2px - 100%); // Offset grows inversely with content height. Initially extends below the viewport, as content grows it offsets up, and reaches a maximum due to max-height of the content
  text-align: left;
  background: white;
}
```

I have tested this in Chrome, FF, Safari, and IE 11.

You can check it out here: http://codepen.io/puopg/pen/vKWJwK

You might even be able to alleviate the abrupt cut off of the character with some CSS magic.

EDIT: I guess one thing that this imposes is word-break: break-all since otherwise the content would not extend to the very end of the viewport. :(

Comment: You don't need to include `word-break: break-all` if you don't mind the floating ellipsis. At this time you have to make a choice between the lesser of those two offenses. Someday when this is supported by default with some standard CSS rule, we'll all look back and have a good laugh.

Comment: It's working fine. Just changed some width and height according to my requirements.

Answer (score 9):

This [man](http://daker.me/snippets/truncate-multiline-text-with-ellipsis-in-css.html) have the best solution. Only css:

```
.multiline-ellipsis {
    display: block;
    display: -webkit-box;
    max-width: 400px;
    height: 109.2px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    font-size: 26px;
    line-height: 1.4;
    -webkit-line-clamp: 3;
    -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

Comment: This is a non standard feature that is no longer supported.

Comment: line-clamp only works in chrome https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-line-clamp

Comment: Again. This only works if you know the amount of lines you will be clamping

Answer (score 5):

Unfortunately no with current state of affairs in CSS.

Ellipsis rendering has prerequisite `white-space:nowrap` that effectively means: ellipsis are drawn on single line text containers only.

Comment: Also haven't found one solution in css that works well. It's all hacky and ugly.

Answer (score 3):

I came up with my own solution for this:

```js
/*this JS code puts the ellipsis (...) at the end of multiline ellipsis elements
 *
 * to use the multiline ellipsis on an element give it the following CSS properties
 * line-height:xxx
 * height:xxx (must line-height * number of wanted lines)
 * overflow:hidden
 *
 * and have the class js_ellipsis
 * */

//do all ellipsis when jQuery loads
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {put_ellipsisses();});

//redo ellipsis when window resizes
var re_ellipsis_timeout;
jQuery( window ).resize(function() {
    //timeout mechanism prevents from chain calling the function on resize
    clearTimeout(re_ellipsis_timeout);
    re_ellipsis_timeout = setTimeout(function(){ console.log("re_ellipsis_timeout finishes"); put_ellipsisses(); }, 500);
});

//the main function
function put_ellipsisses(){
    jQuery(".js_ellipsis").each(function(){

        //remember initial text to be able to regrow when space increases
        var object_data=jQuery(this).data();
        if(typeof object_data.oldtext != "undefined"){
            jQuery(this).text(object_data.oldtext);
        }else{
            object_data.oldtext = jQuery(this).text();
            jQuery(this).data(object_data);
        }

        //truncate and ellipsis
        var clientHeight = this.clientHeight;
        var maxturns=100; var countturns=0;
        while (this.scrollHeight > clientHeight && countturns < maxturns) {
            countturns++;
            jQuery(this).text(function (index, text) {
                return text.replace(/\W*\s(\S)*$/, '...');
            });
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Please check this below code for pure css trick with proper alignment which supports for all browsers

```css
.block-with-text {
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    line-height: 1.2em;
    max-height: 103px;
    text-align: justify;
    padding: 15px;
}

.block-with-text:after {
    content: '...';
    position: absolute;
    right: 15px;
    bottom: -4px;
    background: linear-gradient(to right, #fffff2, #fff, #fff, #fff);
}
```

```html
<p class="block-with-text">The Hitch Hiker's Guide to the Galaxy has a few things to say on the subject of towels. A towel, it says, is about the most massivelyuseful thing an interstellar hitch hiker can have. Partly it has great practical value - you can wrap it around you for warmth as you bound across the cold moons of Jaglan Beta; you can lie on it on the brilliant marble-sanded beaches of Santraginus V, inhaling the heady sea vapours; you can sleep under it beneath the stars which shine so redly on the desert world of Kakrafoon; use it to sail a mini raft down the slow heavy river Moth; wet it for use in hand-to-hand-combat; wrap it round your head to ward off noxious fumes or to avoid the gaze of the Ravenous Bugblatter Beast of Traal (a mindboggingly stupid animal, it assumes that if you can't see it, it can't see you - daft as a bush, but very ravenous); you can wave your towel in emergencies as a distress signal, and of course dry yourself off with it if it still seems to be clean enough. More importantly, a towel has immense psychological value. For some reason, if a strag (strag: non-hitch hiker) discovers that a hitch hiker has his towel with him, he will automatically assume that he is also in possession of a toothbrush, face flannel, soap, tin of biscuits, flask, compass, map, ball of string, gnat spray, wet weather gear, space suit etc., etc. Furthermore, the strag will then happily lend the hitch hiker any of these or a dozen other items that the hitch hiker might accidentally have "lost". What the strag will think is that any man who can hitch the length and breadth of the galaxy, rough it, slum it, struggle against terrible odds, win through, and still knows where his towel is is clearly a man to be reckoned with.</p>
```

Comment: That looks very bad.

Answer (score 2):

May be this can help you guys. Multi Line Ellipses with tooltip hover.
https://codepen.io/Anugraha123/pen/WOBdOb

```
<div>
     <p class="cards-values">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,   consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc aliquet lorem commodo, semper mauris nec, suscipit nisi. Nullam laoreet massa sit amet leo malesuada imperdiet eu a augue. Sed ac diam quis ante congue volutpat non vitae sem. Vivamus a felis id dui aliquam tempus
      </p>
      <span class="tooltip"></span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
You can achieve this by a few lines of CSS and JS.

CSS:

        div.clip-context {
          max-height: 95px;
          word-break: break-all;
          white-space: normal;
          word-wrap: break-word; //Breaking unicode line for MS-Edge works with this property;
        }

JS:

        $(document).ready(function(){
             for(let c of $("div.clip-context")){
                    //If each of element content exceeds 95px its css height, extract some first 
                    //lines by specifying first length of its text content. 
                   if($(c).innerHeight() >= 95){
                        //Define text length for extracting, here 170.
                        $(c).text($(c).text().substr(0, 170)); 
                        $(c).append(" ...");
                   }
             }

        });

HTML:

        <div class="clip-context">
            (Here some text)
        </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

After many tries, I finally ended up with a mixed js / css to handle multiline and single line overflows.

CSS3 code:

```
.forcewrap { // single line ellipsis
  -ms-text-overflow: ellipsis;
  -o-text-overflow: ellipsis;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  overflow: hidden;
  -moz-binding: url( 'bindings.xml#ellipsis' );
  white-space: nowrap;
  display: block;
  max-width: 95%; // spare space for ellipsis
}

.forcewrap.multiline {
  line-height: 1.2em;  // my line spacing 
  max-height: 3.6em;   // 3 lines
  white-space: normal;
}

.manual-ellipsis:after {
  content: "\02026";      // '...'
  position: absolute;     // parent container must be position: relative
  right: 10px;            // typical padding around my text
  bottom: 10px;           // same reason as above
  padding-left: 5px;      // spare some space before ellipsis
  background-color: #fff; // hide text behind
}
```

and I simply check with js code for overflows on divs, like this:

```
function handleMultilineOverflow(div) {
    // get actual element that is overflowing, an anchor 'a' in my case
    var element = $(div).find('a'); 
    // don't know why but must get scrollHeight by jquery for anchors
    if ($(element).innerHeight() < $(element).prop('scrollHeight')) {
        $(element).addClass('manual-ellipsis');
    }
}
```

Usage example in html:

```
<div class="towrap">
  <h4>
    <a class="forcewrap multiline" href="/some/ref">Very long text</a>
  </h4>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Well you could use the line-clamp function in CSS3.

```
p {
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    display: -webkit-box;
    line-height: 25px;
    height: 52px;
    max-height: 52px;
    font-size: 22px;
    -webkit-line-clamp: 2;
    -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
}
```

Make sure you change the settings like you're own.

Answer (score 1):

To bad CSS doesn't support cross-browser multiline clamping, only webkit seems to be pushing it.

You could try and use a simple Javascript ellipsis library like Ellipsity on github the source code is very clean and small so if you do need to make any additional changes it should be quite easy.

https://github.com/Xela101/Ellipsity

Answer (score 1):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        /* styles for '...' */
        .block-with-text {
            width: 50px;
            height: 50px;
            /* hide text if it more than N lines  */
            overflow: hidden;
            /* for set '...' in absolute position */
            position: relative;
            /* use this value to count block height */
            line-height: 1.2em;
            /* max-height = line-height (1.2) * lines max number (3) */
            max-height: 3.6em;
            /* fix problem when last visible word doesn't adjoin right side  */
            text-align: justify;
            /* place for '...' */
            margin-right: -1em;
            padding-right: 1em;
        }
            /* create the ... */
            .block-with-text:before {
                /* points in the end */
                content: '...';
                /* absolute position */
                position: absolute;
                /* set position to right bottom corner of block */
                right: 0;
                bottom: 0;
            }
            /* hide ... if we have text, which is less than or equal to max lines */
            .block-with-text:after {
                /* points in the end */
                content: '';
                /* absolute position */
                position: absolute;
                /* set position to right bottom corner of text */
                right: 0;
                /* set width and height */
                width: 1em;
                height: 1em;
                margin-top: 0.2em;
                /* bg color = bg color under block */
                background: white;
            }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    a
    <div class="block-with-text">g fdsfkjsndasdasd asd asd asdf asdf asdf asdfas dfa sdf asdflk jgnsdlfkgj nsldkfgjnsldkfjgn sldkfjgnls dkfjgns ldkfjgn sldkfjngl sdkfjngls dkfjnglsdfkjng lsdkfjgn sdfgsd</div>
    <p>This is a paragraph.</p>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Source: http://hackingui.com/front-end/a-pure-css-solution-for-multiline-text-truncation/

Answer (score 1):

After looking all over the internet and trying a lot of these options, the only way to make sure that it is covered correctly with support for i.e is through javascript, i created a loop function to go over post items that require multi line truncation.

*note i used Jquery, and requires your post__items class to have a fixed max-height.

```
// loop over post items
$('.post__items').each(function(){
    var textArray = $(this).text().split(' ');
    while($(this).prop('scrollHeight') > $(this).prop('offsetHeight')) {
        textArray.pop();
        $(this).text(textArray.join(' ') + '...');
     }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
p{
line-height: 20px;
width: 157px;
white-space: nowrap; 
overflow: hidden;
text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

or we can restrict the lines by using and height and overflow.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using javascript, maybe you can do something like below.
However, this does not account the height of the container...

```js
// whatever string
const myString = 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum pellentesque sem ut consequat pulvinar. Curabitur vehicula quam sit amet risus aliquet, sed rhoncus tortor fermentum. Etiam ac fermentum nisi. Ut in lobortis eros. Etiam urna felis, interdum sit amet fringilla eu, bibendum et nunc.';

// you can set max string length
const maxStrLength = 100;
const truncatedString = myString.length > maxStrLength ? `${myString.substring(0, maxStrLength)}...` : myString;

console.log(truncatedString);
```

Answer (score -1):

My solution that works for me for multiline ellipsis:

```
.crd-para {
    color: $txt-clr-main;
    line-height: 2rem;
    font-weight: 600;
    margin-bottom: 1rem !important;
    overflow: hidden;

    span::after {
        content: "...";
        padding-left: 0.125rem;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

If you also have multiple elements and you want a link with read more button after ellipsis, take a look on https://stackoverflow.com/a/51418807/10104342

If you want something like this:

> Every month first 10 TB are are not charged. All other traffic... Read more

Answer (score -2):

Pros:
+ Cross browser (IE11, Edge, Chrome, Firefox, Safari, etc.)
+ Most natural looking

Cons:
- Adds lots of extra elements to the DOM

I wasn't satisfied with any of the workarounds I had seen. Most of them use line-clamp which is currently only supported in webkit. So I played around with it until I came up with a solution. This pure javascript solution should be compatible with IE10 and greater and all modern browsers. This is untested outside of the stackoverflow example space below.

I think this is a good solution. The one big caveat is that it creates a span for each word inside the container, which will impact layout performance, so your mileage may vary.

```js
//This is designed to be run on page load, but if you wanted you could put all of this in a function and addEventListener and call it whenever the container is resized.
var $container = document.querySelector('.ellipses-container');

//optional - show the full text on hover with a simple title attribute
$container.title = $container.textContent.trim();

$container.textContent.trim().split(' ').some(function (word) {
  //create a span for each word and append it to the container
  var newWordSpan = document.createElement('span');
  newWordSpan.textContent = word;
  $container.appendChild(newWordSpan);
  
  if (newWordSpan.getBoundingClientRect().bottom > $container.getBoundingClientRect().bottom) {
    //it gets into this block for the first element that has part of itself below the bottom of the container
    //get the last visible element
    var containerChildNodes = $container.childNodes;
    var lastVisibleElement = containerChildNodes[containerChildNodes.length - 2];
    
    //replace this final span with the ellipsis character
    newWordSpan.textContent = '\u2026';
    
    //if the last visible word ended very near the end of the line the ellipsis will have wrapped to the next line, so we need to remove letters from the last visible word
    while (lastVisibleElement.textContent != "" && newWordSpan.getBoundingClientRect().bottom > $container.getBoundingClientRect().bottom) {
      lastVisibleElement.style.marginRight = 0;
      lastVisibleElement.textContent = lastVisibleElement.textContent.slice(0, -1);
    }
    
    //using .some() so that we can short circuit at this point and no more spans will be added
    return true;
  }
});
```

```css
.multi-line-container {
  border: 1px solid lightgrey;
  padding: 4px;
  height: 150px;
  width: 300px;
}

.ellipses-container {
  display: inline-flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  align-content: flex-start; /* optionally use align-content:stretch, the default, if you don't like the extra space at the bottom of the box if there's a half-line gap */
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}

.ellipses-container > span {
  flex: 0 0 auto;
  margin-right: .25em;
}

.text-body {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="multi-line-container ellipses-container">
  <div class="text-body ellipses-text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque luctus ut massa eget porttitor. Nulla a eros sit amet ex scelerisque iaculis nec vitae turpis. Sed pharetra tincidunt ante, in mollis turpis consectetur at. Praesent venenatis pulvinar lectus, at tincidunt nunc finibus non. Duis tortor lectus, elementum faucibus bibendum vitae, egestas bibendum ex. Maecenas vitae augue vitae dui condimentum imperdiet sit amet mattis quam. Duis eleifend scelerisque magna sed imperdiet. Mauris tempus rutrum metus, a ullamcorper erat fringilla a. Suspendisse potenti. Praesent et mi enim. Orci varius natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus.
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Unfortunately, your solution breaks triple-click selections and copy, affecting usability more than those that use absolute-positioning to append the ellipsis.