# Prevent vertical overflow with CSS

Tags: css, overflow

I use this code:

```
.truncated-filename {
    max-width: 100px;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

To prevent filenames from being too long for the box. However, there seems to be a vertical overflow issue. How can I make it so it just puts the dots on the top line?

[image]

Comment: You can use 
`white-space: nowrap;` to make the text follow a single line

Comment: looks something like this  
`.truncated-filename {  
        max-width: 100px;  
        white-space: nowrap;  
        overflow: hidden;  
        text-overflow: ellipsis;  
    }`

Comment: Ellipsis requirements and limitations: http://stackoverflow.com/a/33061059/3597276

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you need to add `overflow: hidden` and `white-space: nowrap`.

The text won't be truncated unless it doesn't wrap, which is why you needed `white-space: nowrap` and an `overflow` value other than `visible`.

```css
.truncated-filename {
  border: 1px solid;
  display: inline-block;
  max-width: 100px;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<span class="truncated-filename">10128-teach-vector.png</span>
```

Comment: *...according to MDN, `text-overflow: ellipsis` only works with `overflow: hidden`..* You may want to revise that. MDN only suggests it as an example. And `text-overflow: ellipsis` will work as long as `overflow` is other than `visible`... http://jsfiddle.net/9t2w7yex/2/ ... In case you're interested, I have a full answer [**here**](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33061059/3597276).