# I am using ng-bind-html but it causing my css text-overflow: ellipsis . How to apply this properties?

Tags: angularjs, html, css

After click i am using class deal which contain this css of  text-overflow: ellipsis. But it is not working because of ng-bind-hml. I can't remove ng-bind-html because my data is coming with some html tags.

```
<p ng-click="notes.notesClass = 'deal-expand';expand=true"  class="deal-collapse" ng-class="notes.notesClass" ng-bind-html="notes.content">
</p>
```

Comment: <p ng-click="notes.notesClass = 'deal-expand';expand=true"  class="deal-collapse" ng-class="notes.notesClass" ng-bind-html="notes.content"></p>

Comment: Your question is a bit unclear to me, but this may help you: http://stackoverflow.com/a/33061059/3597276

Answer (score 0):

The correct way to manipulate classes in Angular is to use dictionaries with `boolean` values like this: `ng-class={'deal-expand':true, 'deal-collapse':false}`. The following code probably do the thing you want:

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope, $sce) {
   $scope.notes=[];
   $scope.notes.content=$sce.trustAsHtml('This is some long text that will not fit in the box');
});
```

```css
.deal-collapse{
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-overflow:ellipsis; 
  width:100px;
  overflow:hidden;
}
.deal-expand{
  text-overflow:inherit;
  overflow: visible;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">

  <p ng-click="notes.notesClass = {'deal-expand':true, 'deal-collapse':false}"  class="deal-collapse" ng-class="notes.notesClass" ng-bind-html="notes.content">
  </p>
</div>
```

You could also take a look at [Animations: the Angular Way](https://css-tricks.com/animations-the-angular-way/) for more details.

Comment: And last but not the least, please try to provide more information in your question so that people who answer understand it better and also it will be more useful for others.