# dynamic content ellipsis based on predefined proportion

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have the following template of a card: [pen](http://codepen.io/MickelSierra85/pen/QEZodK). It is comprised of two sections "one" and "two".

```
<div id="one">
   <div id="two">
  Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's...
   </div>
   <div id="three">
   Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been...
   </div>
</div>
```

Both of the sections have content that overflows their respective size. I would like to maximize `#two div`, so that it will take maximum (and ellipsis the rest) size and leave one line for the `#three div`.

If there is not enough content for `#two` then take its respective size and give all size left to `#three`.

Edit:

I would like to fix the width and allow the height to grow to a certain limit and then ellipsis

Comment: Applying ellipsis to multiline text is a bit of an adventure in CSS: http://stackoverflow.com/q/33058004/3597276

Comment: Thanks. I am searching for a way to use ellipsis with fluid height. i.e. make the div grow in height until certain limit and then ellipsis