# display multiple lines and show ellipsis for text-overflow doesn't work on firefox

Tags: css, firefox

Here's the jsfiddle:
[jsfiddle.net](https://jsfiddle.net/JaneChen/gu7tf864/10/)
.html:

```
  <span class="fileName" >long name file to display long name file to displayddddddssdd moreggggg lines more lines more more more lines</span>
```

.scss:

```
.fileName {

  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -webkit-line-clamp: 3;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical; 

  font-size: 17px;
  line-height:  1.4;
  max-height: 71.4px;


  overflow:hidden;
  display: -webkit-box;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;


  width: 175px;


}
```

The text will not wrap or truncate in Firefox. But wraps and shows ellipsis in Safari and Chrome.

Is  `text-overflow: ellipsis;` supported in Firefox?
I included other parts of scss as I need the text to be shown in 3 lines. So I cannot use `display:inline-block` or `white-space: nowrap;` property.

Is there a workaround for Firefox ? Thanks.

Comment: There is no such thing as `-webkit-box` in the spec. `-webkit-box` is actually a sort-of workaround for old Safari and Chrome versions.

Comment: I tried "box" in the jsfiddle link, it still shows no wrap or truncate.

Comment: You actually need `display: flex`, which is the spec compliant property.

Comment: Display as flex seems like a different thing..  It might be the same as display:block.  But the page stills shows different in Firefox, which doesn't hide overflow or show ellipsis.

Comment: "display:box" doesn't exist

Comment: No, but `display: flex` does. Use that.

Comment: It might be the same effect as display:block. But the page stills shows wrongly, which doesn't hide overflow or show ellipsis.

Comment: Yeah, that's probably because you have a whole bunch of other non-standard CSS properties that simply aren't widely supported. Don't expect anything with vendor prefixes like `-webkit-` to work cross-browser, or necessarily into the future.

Comment: [Applying Ellipsis to Multiline Text](http://stackoverflow.com/q/33058004/3597276)

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
display: -webkit-box;
display: -moz-box;  // Firefox
display: -ms-flexbox;
display: flex;
```

I think only old versions Safari use `display: -webkit-box;`. [more info here](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/).

Comment: Thank you for the reference and answer. I modified my question to include the focus on displaying multiple lines and showing ellipsis of text-overflow. With change you mentioned, the  `overflow:hidden ` and  `text-overflow:ellipsis ` are still not working.

Comment: Thanks. I notice `.fileName` is a `<span>` (and is `display:inline;` by default), have you tried setting it as `display:inline-block;` or `display:block;` so it maintains any height or width give it?