# Adding ellipsis inside table cell without widths

Tags: html, css, html-table, ellipsis

I want to ellipsify the text in the second column without hard-coding a width for either of the two columns. Is this possible where only the parent element (table) has a fixed width?

```css
table {
  width: 100px;
  border: 1px solid green;
}

.td1 {
  border: 1px solid blue;
 }

.td2 {
  border: 1px solid red;
 }

.td div {
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="td1">Label:</td>
    <td class="td2"><div>thequickbrownfoxjumpsoverthelazydog</div></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: I believe the answer is no, with pure CSS. You can get close with `table-layout: fixed` and `overflow: hidden` on the `table` element: https://jsfiddle.net/vpqg4v0n/

Comment: If you're open to JS/jQuery, I've posted some options here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/33061059/3597276

Comment: Thanks, will take a look at http://dotdotdot.frebsite.nl/

Comment: Just wondering is this question still open since no accepted answer yet?

Answer (score 5):

You can do that within a nested table, I use a CSS table for the example, and added a span tag into the div for the table layout.

**[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xrp7cspf/)**

```css
table {
  width: 200px;
  border: 1px solid green;
}
.td1 {
  border: 1px solid blue;
}
.td2 {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
.td2 div {
  display: table;
  table-layout: fixed;
  width: 100%;
}
.td2 span {
  display: table-cell;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="td1">Label:</td>
    <td class="td2">
      <div><span>thequickbrownfoxjumpsoverthelazydog</span></div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Very elegant. It will also work on fluid width tables without `width: 200px;`

Answer (score 1):

You need `table-layout: fixed;`

More info - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/table-layout

The CSS for the ellipsis part is ok, but what happens is that, by default, a table calculates its width based on the content width, so the table cell would be as wide as the content, and the text would never be collapsed. `table-layout: fixed;` changes that. It means the table will calculate the dimensions of the cells **before** inserting the content, then the content will not affect the table's dimensions when rendered.

The tradeoff is that your table will no longer balance the columns automatically:

```css
table {
  width: 100px;
  border: 1px solid green;
  table-layout: fixed;
}

.td1 {
  border: 1px solid blue;
 }

.td2 {
  border: 1px solid red;
 }

td div {
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="td1">Label:</td>
    <td class="td2"><div>thequickbrownfoxjumpsoverthelazydog</div></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```