# text-overflow: ellipsis and flex

Tags: javascript, html, css, flexbox

I have a container element with `display: flex` property set.
A children have fixed width (`flex: 0 0 auto`), another one no (`flex: 1`). The flexible children has some other children: I want this container (`inner`) to clip its children according to the parent width.

I managed to do this, but also I'd like to get the *ellipsis* overflow in case the content is clipped (the number of children is not fixed).

This is my code so far:

```
.outer {
  border: 1px solid red;
  display: flex;
  width: 400px;
}

.inner {
  display: flex;
  min-width: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  flex: 1;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}

.child {
  display: inline-block;
  white-space: nowrap;
  flex: 1;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}

.btn {
  border: 1px solid green;
  flex: 0 0 auto;
}
```

Live here: http://jsbin.com/niheyiwiya/edit?html,css,output

How can I get the following desired result? (hacks welcome - css only please!)

[image]

Comment: The ellipsis css attribute will not work for this since you are attempting to use it on elements, not text.

Comment: One thing you can do is give the ```.inner``` class property of ```flex-wrap: wrap```

Comment: `display:flex` is not a block container; it is, unsurprisingly, a flex container.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

There are a few problems with your layout:

1. `text-overflow: ellipsis` only works with `display: block` and `display: inline-block` containers. It's failing because you have `.inner` set to `display: flex`.
2. `text-overflow: ellipsis` must include `white-space: nowrap` in the same declaration. It's missing in your `.inner` rule.
3. ellipsis works on text, not block-level elements

Try this:

```css
* {
  margin: 15px 1px
}
.outer {
  border: 1px solid red;
  display: flex;
  width: 400px;
}
.inner {
  /* display: flex */          /* removed */
  min-width: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  flex: 1;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;         /* new */
}
.child {
  display: inline;             /* adjusted */
  white-space: nowrap;
  flex: 1;
}
.btn {
  border: 1px solid green;
  flex: 0 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  <div class="inner">
    <div class="child">child 1</div>
    <div class="child">child 2</div>
    <div class="child">child 3</div>
    <div class="child">child 4</div>
    <div class="child">child 5</div>
    <div class="child">child 6</div>
    <div class="child">child 7</div>
  </div>
  <div class="btn">My big big big button!</div>
</div>
```

More about `text-overflow: ellipsis` here: [Applying an ellipsis to multiline text](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33058004/3597276)

Answer (score 2):

Here is JS approach where you could find which `child` div have position that overflows with position of button, and hide all divs after that div and append `...` after that div.

```js
var child = $('.child');
var btn = $('.btn');
var oW = $('.outer').innerWidth();
var w = btn.outerWidth();
var c = oW - w;
var last;

child.each(function() {
  var l = $(this).position().left + $(this).outerWidth();
  if (l > c) {
    if (last == undefined) last = $(this).index() - 1;
  }
})

$('.child:gt(' + last + ')').css('display', 'none');
$('.child:eq(' + last + ')').after(' ...')
```

```css
* {
  margin: 15px 1px
}
.outer {
  border: 1px solid red;
  display: flex;
  width: 400px;
}
.inner {
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  flex: 1;
}
.child {
  border: 1px solid blue;
  display: inline-block;
}
.btn {
  border: 1px solid green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="outer">
  <div class="inner">
    <div class="child">child 1</div>
    <div class="child">child 2</div>
    <div class="child">child 3</div>
    <div class="child">child 4</div>
    <div class="child">child 5</div>
    <div class="child">child 6</div>
    <div class="child">child 7</div>
  </div>
  <div class="btn">My big big big button!</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

A great example with `min-width: 0;` which just works: https://css-tricks.com/flexbox-truncated-text/

BUT:

If your text to trancate is inside the a-tag, than you have to wrap that a-tag, in e.g. h2 or p. Otherwise the text will not be truncated because of the a-tag!

So here is the working example with the a-tag basing on example above:

```css
.flex-parent {
 display: flex;
 align-items: center;
}

.long-and-truncated-with-child-corrected {
 flex: 1;
 min-width: 0;
  /* or some value */;
}

.long-and-truncated-with-child-corrected h2 {
 white-space: nowrap;
 overflow: hidden;
 text-overflow: ellipsis;
}

.short-and-fixed {
 white-space: nowrap;
}

.short-and-fixed > div {
 width: 30px;
 height: 30px;
 border-radius: 10px;
 background: lightgreen;
 display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-parent">

      <div class="long-and-truncated-with-child-corrected">
        <h2>
          <a href="https://duckduckgo.com">333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333</a>
        </h2>
    
      </div>
      <div class="long-and-truncated-with-child-corrected">
        <h2>
          <a href="https://vgn.de">
            44444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444
          </a>
        </h2>
      </div>
      <div class="short-and-fixed">
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
      </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the previous answer:

if you nest the flex-elements, than you have to add

`white-space: nowrap;
 overflow: hidden;
 text-overflow: ellipsis;`

to the parent container otherwise the hiding of the overflow may not work any more.

In some cases you need `width: 0;` in addition/instead of to `min-width: 0;`.