# CSS multi-line text ellipsis with room for read more link?

Tags: css

I wonder if there is a CSS-only solution to have a paragraph that ends with `ellipsis` but also let add a "read more" link at the very end on the same line of text.

eg.

**regular ellipsis**

> Ultrices natoque mus mattis, aliquam, cras in pellentesque tincidunt
>   elit purus lectus, vel ut aliquet, elementum...

**"read more"**

> Ultrices natoque mus mattis, aliquam, cras in pellentesque tincidunt
>   elit purus lectus, vel ut aliqu... Read More >

Comment: possible duplicate: [Applying an ellipsis to multiline text](http://stackoverflow.com/q/33058004/3597276)

Comment: This 2021 anyone get any solution at css or js solution about this issues ?

Answer (score 2):

Here's one attempt. It sorta works, although you might have to adjust the styling on the `<a>` to cater for font changes and such

```css
.truncate {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 250px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
.truncate + a {
display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  margin-top: -1px;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <p><span class="truncate">This is a text that should be truncated because it's too long</span><a href="#">Read more</a></p>
  </div>
```

Comment: The problem with this approach is that `<a href="#">Read more</a>` always needs to be included. If you have some posts with content that is too long, this is fine. But if you also have some posts with no content or content that is less than the width where truncation is necessary, then "Read more" would appear, which isn't desired.