# How to make a multiline overflow text ellipsis with a read more link at the end?

Tags: javascript, html, css, frontend, web-frontend

I have this container and I want it to be rendered like this:

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
Nulla ac neque sed velit aliquet molestie. Duis ut
magna euismod, convallis tellus... Read More.
```

I've tried this. It worked for the text but regarding the link, it's just displaying on another line obviously. Also the link should be kind of a part of the text but if I add the anchor element inside the paragraph element it'll hide it since now it's part of the text.

```css
.text {
  display: -webkit-box;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  -webkit-line-clamp: 3;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <p class="text">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla ac neque sed velit aliquet molestie. Duis ut magna euismod, convallis tellus non, molestie risus. Aenean lacinia nisl eget tincidunt bibendum.
  </p>
  <a href="#" class="read-more">Read More</a>
</div>
```

Comment: You can move the <a> link inside the paragraph and wrap the text into a span tag moving here the "text" class. However, you will always see the read more on the following line since you are cutting by line.

Comment: There's a similar question here but only one liner https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40351604/css-multi-line-text-ellipsis-with-room-for-read-more-link.  I don't think what you want is possible without using js.

Comment: if adding js can solve the problem sure. Also i have seen lots of one liner solutions but that's not what i need.

Comment: Why can't you apply `display: flex` to the container? It should give your desired  results.