# CSS- Automatically shorten long strings using ellipsis

Tags: html, css

Hi i am shortening long strings using ellipsis and putting dotes(...) at end. The problem is if a string contains space then i want to break string first then if it overflows then put dotes(...). E.g. I have two strings

```
Choreographers  Farm Houses
```

If i don't use ellipsis then on resizing window Choreographers overlaps Farm Houses...

When i use ellipsis then on resizing window i get

```
Choreogra...    Farm Ho...
```

What i want is

```
Choreogra...      Farm
                  Houses
```

And in case of more smaller screen

```
Chore...         Farm
                 Hous...
```

**Fiddle:**  https://jsfiddle.net/7fpt4m5e/3/

Comment: `text-overflow: ellipsis;` works only for single lines.

Comment: @connexo Okay thanks...Is it possible to achieve what i want ??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Remove the `white-space: nowrap` ... though [`text-overflow`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/text-overflow) has bad browser support for multiline

[Updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/LGSon/7fpt4m5e/5/)

```
.block2 p {
  overflow:hidden;
  text-overflow:ellipsis;
  width:98%;
}
```

Check this post, [applying-an-ellipsis-to-multiline-text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33058004/applying-an-ellipsis-to-multiline-text), there you will find many more ways how to

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, `text-overflow: ellipsis` will only truncate single lines.

However what you can do here is to use `line-clamp` which should work on webkit browsers & Firefox.

Here you mention the number of lines you want after which truncation to happen in `-webkit-line-clamp` & `-moz-line-clamp`.

Example of a `line-clamp` usage is:

```css
div {
  max-height: 42px;
  width: 40px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  font-size: 16px;
  overflow: hidden;
  color: #000;
  display: -webkit-box;
  -webkit-line-clamp: 2;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  -moz-line-clamp: 2;
  -moz-box-orient: vertical;
}
```

```html
<div>the quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog</div>
<div>the quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog</div>
```

Otherwise, you can go the handle-your-own-pseudo-selectors-with-content-("...") way too.

Answer (score -1):

Instead of writing "Farm Houses" you should write "`Farm&nbsp;Houses`", this way it does the effect you want to achieve. This solution also answers to the bad support in browsers of `white-space: nowrap` or text-overflow

https://jsfiddle.net/7fpt4m5e/6/

Works on all browsers as it doesn't need special support.