# Angular2 - limit number of lines inside p

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular

I am looking for a way to truncate a `<p>` tag to a given number of lines (with a trailing `...`).

Using a number of characters doesn't work since the width of the element depends on device screen width.

Comment: Could you please include some code here as to how your `<p>` tag looks like, what did you try?

Comment: This isn't really an Angular 2 question. Take a look css [`text-overflow`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/text-overflow)

Comment: @ChristopherMoore text-overflow works for one line. for n lines It seems like an Angular 2 pipe is necessary

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Applying an ellipsis to multiline text](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33058004/applying-an-ellipsis-to-multiline-text)

Comment: @younesyounes you're right - I didn't realise `text-overflow` doesn't work for multi-line text. A duplicate SO question linked in the comment above should help you get the desired effect

Answer (score -4):

You don't need angular.  Just CSS.  Set a height and a text-overflow property.

something like this:

```
p{
  height: 200px;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

You'll have to figure out the number of pixels that corresponds with the number of lines you want.  For example, if you want 10 lines to show, and each line has a height of 20px, the height will need to be 200px.