# text-overflow: ellipsis is not working

Tags: html, css

I can't get `text-overflow: ellipsis` to work and I hope someone can spot the mistake I can't find. Here is my code:

HTML:

```
<div class="out">
    <div class="in1"></div>
    <div class="in2">some long random text which should not fit in here</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.out {
    display: block;
    height: 60px;
    width: 250px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #eee;
    cursor: pointer;
    color: #000;
    background: lightgreen;
}

.in1 {
    height: 60px;
    width: 60px;
    padding: 10px;
    float: left;
    border: 1px solid red;
}

.in2 {
    float: left;
    height: 60px;
    line-height: 60px;
    width: 190px;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    overflow: hidden;
    font-size: 1.1em;
    border: 1px solid blue;
}
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/59m5e6ex/

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33061059/2762095), but as far as I can tell, my `div` meets every requirement.

Comment: Just add white-space: nowrap: to your .in2 class

Comment: add `white-space: nowrap;` should help

Comment: Also explained in this [ellipsis not working](https://semicolon.dev/tutorial/css/text-overflow-ellipsis-doesnt-work) article.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to add `white-space: nowrap` to the element with ellipsis type of text-overflow. Otherwise, the text is wrapped to the new line every time and no text-overflow is detected.

Here is your working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/59m5e6ex/2/

So, you need at least 3 properties to run `text-overflow: ellipsis;`:

```
element {
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

Also, if you cannot use any of the needed properties here is the javascript you can use for adding "3 dots" at the end of the text.

```
/**
 * @param  text          string       - text to shorten
 * @param  maxTextLength int          - desired max length of shorten string
 * @return ret           string       - new shortened string
 */
function shorten(text, maxTextLength) {
    var ret = text;
    if (ret.length > maxTextLength) {
        ret = ret.substr(0,maxTextLength-3) + "...";
    }
    return ret;
}
```

It would return a new string with the specified maximum length. But of course, it will change its value. More in this topic can be found [here](https://software.intel.com/en-us/html5/hub/blogs/ellipse-my-text/)

Answer (score 2):

You need

```
white-space: nowrap;
```

in your `in2` class, else the text wraps onto a new line.

See https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/truncate-string-with-ellipsis/ for more details. :)

Comment: Oh god, thank you, I'm an idiot :D

Answer (score -1):

just add white-space:nowrap; in .in2;
See this example from w3schools: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_text-overflow.asp