# Prevent a child element from overflowing its parent in flexbox

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm working on a web app that shows a large grid of cards, the height of which is inherently variable.

In the interests of aesthetics, we were using jQuery's `.matchHeight()` to equalise the height of cards within each row.

The performance of that didn't scale well, so today I've been migrating to a flex-box based solution which is so much faster.

However, I've lost a behaviour - the content of the card header should be truncated with an ellipsis if it won't fit.

Goals:

1. 3 columns
2. Column widths vary to fill parent
3. Constant spacing between columns
4. Heights equalised within a row

How do I arrange for the container size to be respected and the `text-overflow: ellipsis;` and `white-space: nowrap;` to be honoured?

(No jQuery tag as we're moving away from that)

My solution in it's current form, which achieves all of my goals apart from the truncation:

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/QvqZYY

```css
#container { 
                display: flex; 
                flex-direction: row; 
                flex-wrap: wrap; 
                
                justify-content: flex-start;    /* Bias cards to stack from left edge       */ 
                align-items: stretch;           /* Within a row, all cards the same height  */ 
                
                border: thin solid gray; 
            } 
            .card-wrapper { 
                width: 33.33%; 
                display: flex; 
                background: #e0e0ff; 
            } 
            .card { 
                flex-grow: 1; 
                margin: 7px; 
                display: flex; 
                flex-direction: column; 
                border: thin solid gray; 
                background: #e0ffff; 
            } 
            .card div { 
                border: thin solid gray; 
            } 
            .card div:nth-child(1) { 
                white-space: nowrap; 
                text-overflow: ellipsis; 
            } 
            .card div:nth-child(2) { 
                flex-grow: 2; 
            }
```

```html
<div id="container"> 
            <div class="card-wrapper"> 
                <div class="card"> 
                    <div>Title</div> 
                    <div>Multiline<br/>Body</div> 
                    <div>Footer</div> 
                </div> 
            </div> 
            <div class="card-wrapper"><div class="card"><div>Really long rambling title that pushes beyond the bounds of the container, unless your screen is really, really wide</div><div>Body</div><div>Footer</div></div></div> 
            <div class="card-wrapper"><div class="card"><div>Title</div><div>Body</div><div>Footer</div></div></div> 
            <div class="card-wrapper"><div class="card"><div>Title</div><div>Body</div><div>Footer</div></div></div> 
            <div class="card-wrapper"><div class="card"><div>Title</div><div>Body</div><div>Footer</div></div></div> 
        </div>
```

Answer (score 210, accepted):

An initial setting on flex items is `min-width: auto`. This means that a flex item, by default, cannot be smaller than the size of its content.

Therefore, `text-overflow: ellipsis` cannot work because a flex item will simply expand, rather than permit an overflow. (Scroll bars will not render either, for the same reason.)

To override this behavior, use `min-width: 0` or `overflow: hidden`. [More details.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36247140/3597276)

```css
#container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  border: thin solid gray;
}

.card-wrapper {
  width: 33.33%;
  display: flex;
  background: #e0e0ff;
}

.card {
  flex-grow: 1;
  margin: 7px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  border: thin solid gray;
  background: #e0ffff;
  overflow: hidden;        /* NEW */
}

.card div {
  border: thin solid gray;
}

.card div:nth-child(1) {
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  overflow: hidden;        /* NEW */
}

.card div:nth-child(2) {
  flex-grow: 2;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div class="card-wrapper">
    <div class="card">
      <div>Title</div>
      <div>Multiline<br/>Body</div>
      <div>Footer</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="card-wrapper">
    <div class="card">
      <div>Really long rambling title that pushes beyond the bounds of the container, unless your screen is really, really wide</div>
      <div>Body</div>
      <div>Footer</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="card-wrapper">
    <div class="card">
      <div>Title</div>
      <div>Body</div>
      <div>Footer</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="card-wrapper">
    <div class="card">
      <div>Title</div>
      <div>Body</div>
      <div>Footer</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="card-wrapper">
    <div class="card">
      <div>Title</div>
      <div>Body</div>
      <div>Footer</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: No reason to pick one over the other in terms of the flex minimum sizing issue. But there is a difference in terms of general CSS. `min-width: 0` will allow the item to shrink, but the content can visibly overflow ([you can test this in your codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/NjaEMK)) ...

Comment: With `overflow: hidden` the same minimum sizing objective is achieved, but overflow content is hidden. Plus, [the `overflow` property is necessary for `text-overflow: ellipsis` to work](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33061059/3597276).

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. `overflow: hidden;` it is then.

Comment: `min-width: 0` fixed my issue which was similar. I had placed `max-width: x` on my container so text overflow would work but that would push other items out of the container on responsive. `min-width: 0` prevented that :) Thanks!

Comment: There are some cases where you do want to have some content sticking out (for instance: `position: absolute` stuff) in which case the `min-width:0` solution is the only way to go

Comment: `min-width: 0` on flex children is just what I was looking for.  Makes text overflow work perfectly.  Thanks!