# How to stop flex from overflowing the parent

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Concider the following HTML/CSS from this [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/roboroads/0hugqso8/21/)

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

main {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  font-size: 5rem;
}

.fill-rest {
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-items: start;
  background-color: green;
}

.fill-rest div {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<main>
  <div>Some Text!</div>
  <div>Some Text!</div>
  <div class="fill-rest">
    <div>Overflowing</div>
    <div>Overflowing</div>
    <div>Overflowing</div>
    <div>Overflowing</div>
    <div>Overflowing</div>
    <div>Overflowing</div>
  </div>
</main>
```

Why - if the divs with "Overflowing" are not present, the height of the element is exactly how I'd want, but as soon as you add too much elements the `.fill-rest` height becomes 100% of the parent instead of "the remaining space"?

I trying to find a way to make the `.fill-rest` not overflow `main` and start wrapping when the remaining space is occupied.

Comment: `display: inline-flex;` ?

Comment: @Kameron Does not seem to work. You can test it in the provided fiddle.

Comment: It's not very clear what you'd like to achieve. The sample works exactly as it's in the CSS, the green div is 100%.

Answer (score 0):

Change your `.fill-rest` class like this:

```css
.fill-rest {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap !important;
  background-color: green;
}
```

[Working example](https://jsfiddle.net/ocp2usdr/40/) (Try to resize the window to see the wrap of the divs).

Comment: This makes the `.fill-rest` class never wrap, since it just grabs all the height it wants. I need `main` to be not overflown, so when `.fill-rest` is full it should start wrapping in the width.

Comment: I updated my answer. Can you try it again?

Comment: I would like to keep the flex behaviour `flex-direction: column;` - in which case this does not solve my problem.

Comment: If you add `flex-direction: column;` that will put each item of the `.fill-rest` in the new row.

Answer (score 0):

After some other search terms, I found out the following [from this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43809612/prevent-a-child-element-from-overflowing-its-parent-in-flexbox):

> An initial setting on flex items is min-width: auto. This means that a flex item, by default, cannot be smaller than the size of its content.

Adding `min-height: 0;` sovled my problem:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

main {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  font-size: 5rem;
}

.fill-rest {
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-items: start;
  background-color: green;
  min-height: 0;
}

.fill-rest div {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<main>
  <div>Some Text!</div>
  <div>Some Text!</div>
  <div class="fill-rest">
    <div>Overflowing</div>
    <div>Overflowing</div>
    <div>Overflowing</div>
    <div>Overflowing</div>
    <div>Overflowing</div>
    <div>Overflowing</div>
  </div>
</main>
```

Comment: I added a duplicate flag to this post - sorry!