# Images in a flex-box looks different in Chrome and Firefox - how to make them look like in Firefox?

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, firefox, flexbox

The desired result:
[image]

It looks different in Chrome. I tried adding `flex: 0 0` to images. But it looks like I can not influence their size. Can I make it look like in Firefox without div wrappers for images and without setting the size of images?

```css
div {
  display: flex;
  gap: 5vw;
}

img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <img src="https://place-hold.it/1280x1024" alt="">
  <img src="https://place-hold.it/1280x1024" alt="">
  <img src="https://place-hold.it/1280x1024" alt="">
</div>
```

Here is the jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ogbva8n5/

UPD: when I set any random width to images in px - they start acting as they should. Seems like it is some bug in Chrome, isn't it?

Comment: Just add min-width: 0 to the img rule. Explanation [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43809765/12571484)

Comment: @Adam thanks, it works too! But how?!?! Would never thought about it. Thanks!

Comment: It's because min-width overrides width. See [this](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/m/min-width/) on CSS tricks. If it's not set the flex container fits the image. If you set min-width to zero you're telling the browser that it can shrink the image down, to 0 if necessary so the flex box does just that to the point it fits the screen width

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do so by hiding the overflow:

```css
div {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  gap: 5vw;
}

div > img {
overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <img src="https://place-hold.it/1280x1024" alt="">
  <img src="https://place-hold.it/1280x1024" alt="">
  <img src="https://place-hold.it/1280x1024" alt="">
</div>
```

Comment: Glad I could help out! You could also replace the "overflown: hidden" with @Adam's solution; "min-width: 0".