# Flex container works differently in different browsers?

Tags: html, css, web

I am making a web-site. There is content part with specific width. Inside there are flex-boxes with image. The number of images may be different (not more than 5) and the width of each image must be calculated to fit them all.

The strange thing is that in `FireFox` this work fine, but in `Chrome` or `Yandex`.

Seem, that images don't auto-fit in flex-box, because of `height: 400px;` the `width: 100%`  tries to correspond that `400px` height.

Here is HTML and CSS parts:

#### HTML

```
<div class="article-images">
    <img src="../images/newsImages/img_6_4.jpg" class="article-images-item" />
    <img src="../images/newsImages/img_6_5.jpg" class="article-images-item" />
    <img src="../images/newsImages/img_6_6.jpg" class="article-images-item" />
    <img src="../images/newsImages/img_6_9.jpg" class="article-images-item" />
</div>
```

#### CSS

```
.article-images {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: space-evenly; 
    gap: 20px; 
    width: 100%
}
.article-images-item {
    width: 100%;
    height: 400px;
    object-fit: cover;
    border-radius: 2px;
    cursor: pointer
}
```

#### How it should be (current in FireFox):

[image: How should be]

#### How it looks now (in Chrome or other browser)

[image: How it looks n]

Answer (score 0):

The following example should help solve it (though we didn't use object-fit in this example).
You can optionally set it up without the image DIV's:
[stack post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75338057/images-in-a-flex-box-looks-different-in-chrome-and-firefox-how-to-make-them-lo)

```css
.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  justify-content: center;
  background-color: rgb(0,150,255);
  align-items: stretch;
}

.flex-container > div {
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  width: 200px; /*--control image size--*/
  margin: 5px;
  border: 2px solid #fff;
  border-radius: 7px;
}

img {
  width: 100%; 
  height:auto; 
  border-radius: 5px; 
  cursor: pointer; 
  display: block; 
  margin-left: auto; 
  margin-right: auto;
}
#outer {padding:2px;}
```

```html
<div id="outer">
<div class="flex-container">
    <div style="flex-grow: 1 3 1"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/100x100.gif?text=1"></div>
    <div style="flex-grow: 1 3 1"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/100x100.gif?text=2"></div>
    <div style="flex-grow: 1 3 1"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/100x100.gif?text=3"></div>
    <div style="flex-grow: 1 3 1"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/100x100.gif?text=4"></div>
</div> 
</div>
```