# Issues combining display:flex, tables, and text-overflow: ellipsis

Tags: html, css, flexbox, ellipsis

I've got a problem combining (top downwards) `display:flex`, flex items, table and then cells containing text that I want to truncate without affecting the width of the flex items, nor pushing the table outside of the flex item.

Truncating text works fine if placed in an `inline-block` inside the flex item, but when I sit a table/row/cell between the two, the table goes haywire.

I've looked at [Setting ellipsis on text from a flex container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45290956/setting-ellipsis-on-text-from-a-flex-container), but that doesn't consider `table` elements, nor does this [CSS Tricks](https://css-tricks.com/flexbox-truncated-text/) example.  I've also used these references to set up my [flexboxes](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/).

Here is my [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/BloodBaz/kcw5cz7u/) example and also:

```css
/* flex layout */
.flex-space-between {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
.flex-space-between > div {
  width:100%;
  flex: 1 1 auto;
}
.flex-with-gap { margin: -14px -7px; }
.flex-with-gap > div { margin: 14px 7px; }


/* colouring and other styles */
.flex-space-between > div {
  box-sizing:border-box;
  background-color:white;
  border: solid 1px #999;
  padding: 0.5em;min-width: 0;
}
body { font-family: sans-serif }

.truncate {
  width:100%;
  display: inline-block;
  color:red;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}

.t1 {
  width: 100%;
  border-collapse:collapse;
}
.t1 TD, .t1 TH {
  border:1px dotted blue;
}
.t1 TH {
  text-align:left;
  font-weight:normal;
}
.t1 .number {
  text-align:right;
  font-size: 180%;
  color:#66F;font-weight:bold;
}
.t1 .text {
  max-width:80%;
}

.info { color: blue; font-style:italic;}
```

```html
<div class='flex-space-between flex-with-gap'>
  <div>
    <div class='truncate'>Mauris mauris ante, blandit et, ultrices a, suscipit eget, quam.</div>
    <p class='info'>The div.truncate element above truncates fine.</p>
  </div>
  
  <div>
  <div class='flex-space-between'>
     <div class='truncate'>Mauris mauris ante, blandit et, ultrices a, suscipit eget, quam.</div>
    <div class='truncate'>Mauris mauris ante, blandit et, ultrices a, suscipit eget, quam.</div>
    </div>
    <p class='info'>So do the above which are contained inside sub-flexboxes.</p>
  </div>

  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</div>

<div class='flex-space-between flex-with-gap'>
  <div></div>
  <div>
   <table class='t1'>
  <tr>
    <th class='text'>Locations</th>
    <td class='number'>123</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th class='text'>Divisions</th>
    <td class='number'>123</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th class='text'>Business Units Business Units Business Units</th>
    <td class='number'>80</td>
  </tr>
  </table>
  <p class='info'>Now, I'm wanting to place a small table in my flex items as above (lists of text and numeric values) but I want the text (e.g. Business Units) to truncate if has to, and not wrap.</p>
  </div>
  
  <div>
  <table class='t1'>
  <tr>
    <th class='text'>Locations</th>
    <td class='number'>123</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th class='text'>Divisions</th>
    <td class='number'>123</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th class='text'><div class='truncate'>Business Units Business Units Business Units</div></th>
    <td class='number'>80</td>
  </tr>
  </table>
  <p class='info'>But this is what now happens when trucating. The "white-space: nowrap;" kicks in but not the "overflow: hidden;" nor "text-overflow: ellipsis;".</p>
    <p class='info'>
    I think truncating text inside a TD/TH is the problem but not sure why.
  </p>
  </div>
  <div style='opacity:0.9'></div>
</div>

<div class='flex-space-between flex-with-gap'>
  <div>100%</div>
</div>

<div class='flex-space-between flex-with-gap'>
  <div>33%</div><div>33%</div><div>33%</div>
</div>

<div class='flex-space-between flex-with-gap'>
  <div>50%<br>Multi-line line</div><div>50%</div>
</div>

<div class='flex-space-between flex-with-gap'>
  <div>25%</div><div>25%</div><div>25%</div><div>25%</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should switch to the *other* table layout algorithm: `table-layout: fixed`, the one that does what the author (you) says and doesn't try to adapt automagically to content. If you're having problems with widths set, try to set them on first row.
Also `max-width` property on cells has no effect AFAIK. Oops no, it's [undefined behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8465980/137626). I changed it to `width: 55%` which is kind of fine here on SO but I guess your page is larger than snippets here so YMMV.

```css
/* flex layout */
.flex-space-between {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
.flex-space-between > div {
  width:100%;
  flex: 1 1 auto;
}
.flex-with-gap { margin: -14px -7px; }
.flex-with-gap > div { margin: 14px 7px; }


/* colouring and other styles */
.flex-space-between > div {
  box-sizing:border-box;
  background-color:white;
  border: solid 1px #999;
  padding: 0.5em;min-width: 0;
}
body { font-family: sans-serif }

.truncate {
  width:100%;
  display: inline-block;
  color:red;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}

.t1 {
  width: 100%;
  border-collapse:collapse;
  table-layout: fixed;
}
.t1 TD, .t1 TH {
  border:1px dotted blue;
}
.t1 TH {
  text-align:left;
  font-weight:normal;
}
.t1 .number {
  text-align:right;
  font-size: 180%;
  color:#66F;font-weight:bold;
}
.t1 .text {
  width: 55%;
  background: yellow;
}

.info { color: blue; font-style:italic;}
```

```html
<div class='flex-space-between flex-with-gap'>
  <div>
    <div class='truncate'>Mauris mauris ante, blandit et, ultrices a, suscipit eget, quam.</div>
    <p class='info'>The div.truncate element above truncates fine.</p>
  </div>
  
  <div>
  <div class='flex-space-between'>
     <div class='truncate'>Mauris mauris ante, blandit et, ultrices a, suscipit eget, quam.</div>
    <div class='truncate'>Mauris mauris ante, blandit et, ultrices a, suscipit eget, quam.</div>
    </div>
    <p class='info'>So do the above which are contained inside sub-flexboxes.</p>
  </div>

  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</div>

<div class='flex-space-between flex-with-gap'>
  <div></div>
  <div>
   <table class='t1'>
  <tr>
    <th class='text'>Locations</th>
    <td class='number'>123</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th class='text'>Divisions</th>
    <td class='number'>123</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th class='text'>Business Units Business Units Business Units</th>
    <td class='number'>80</td>
  </tr>
  </table>
  <p class='info'>Now, I'm wanting to place a small table in my flex items as above (lists of text and numeric values) but I want the text (e.g. Business Units) to truncate if has to, and not wrap.</p>
  </div>
  
  <div>
  <table class='t1'>
  <tr>
    <th class='text'>Locations</th>
    <td class='number'>123</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th class='text'>Divisions</th>
    <td class='number'>123</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th class='text'><div class='truncate'>Business Units Business Units Business Units</div></th>
    <td class='number'>80</td>
  </tr>
  </table>
  <p class='info'>But this is what now happens when trucating. The "white-space: nowrap;" kicks in but not the "overflow: hidden;" nor "text-overflow: ellipsis;".</p>
    <p class='info'>
    I think truncating text inside a TD/TH is the problem but not sure why.
  </p>
  </div>
  <div style='opacity:0.9'></div>
</div>

<div class='flex-space-between flex-with-gap'>
  <div>100%</div>
</div>

<div class='flex-space-between flex-with-gap'>
  <div>33%</div><div>33%</div><div>33%</div>
</div>

<div class='flex-space-between flex-with-gap'>
  <div>50%<br>Multi-line line</div><div>50%</div>
</div>

<div class='flex-space-between flex-with-gap'>
  <div>25%</div><div>25%</div><div>25%</div><div>25%</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks @FelipeAls, I forgot about `table-layout: fixed` - I don't often use it.  I'll give it a go now . Thanks.  That's superb.

Comment: It was very useful on IE8+ (close to Flexbox without wrap) but now with Flexbox without or with wrap (Android 4.4+, old enough), table is seldomly useful, sure :)