# Vertical-align doesn't work on flex item

Tags: html, css, flexbox, vertical-alignment

I tried to vertically centralize plain text inside a flex box element.

I decided to use property `display:table-cell` with `vertical-align: middle`. But it doesn't seem to work properly in flexbox elements.

How can I centralize it vertically, ideally without using a wrapper or positioning, and while still truncating long text with ellipses?

```css
.container {
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  font-weight: 700;
  border: 1px solid #d9d9d9;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.item {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  flex: 1 1;
  background-color: cyan;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}

.item:nth-of-type(2n) {
  background-color: aliceblue;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item">Hello, I'm very very long string! Hello, I'm very very long string!</div>
  <div class="item">Hello</div>
  <div class="item">Hello</div>
  <div class="item">Hello</div>
</div>
```

[View On CodePen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/oGVdjG)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One solution is to define each flex item as its own flex container in order to vertically center its contents with [`align-items:center`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/align-items). To keep `text-overflow` working, add a child element to each flex item, which can then be truncated with ellipses.

I can't offer a succinct explanation as to why `text-overflow` doesn't work with `display:flex`, and [neither can David Wesst](http://www.westerndevs.com/css/Using-Overflow-Ellipsis-in-Inline-Flex/). In his words:

> It turns out that there really isn't a clean way to do this. If you're wondering how I came to that conclusion you can stop because I didn't. Those responsible for the specification did, and you can read the full conversation that started with a [Mozilla bug report](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=912434) and leads to a [whole mail group discussion](http://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/www-style/2013Sep/0070.html) about why it should (or, in this case, should not) be implemented as part of the spec.

Here's a working example:

```css
.container {
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  font-weight: 700;
  border: 1px solid #d9d9d9;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.item {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  flex: 1;
  background-color: cyan;
}

.item span {
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}

.item:nth-of-type(2n) {
  background-color: aliceblue;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item"><span>Hello, I'm very very long string! Hello, I'm very very long string!</span></div>
  <div class="item"><span>Hello</span></div>
  <div class="item"><span>Hello</span></div>
  <div class="item"><span>Hello</span></div>
</div>
```

Also see:
[Setting ellipsis on text from a flex container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45290956/setting-ellipsis-on-text-from-a-flex-container)

Answer (score 4):

When you make an element a flex container (with `display: flex` or `display: inline-flex`), all in-flow children become flex items.

All flex items have their `display` value controlled by the container. It doesn't matter what you specify, the container overrides it.

So when you give a flex item `display: table-cell`, the browser ignores it. Here's what it looks like in Chrome Dev Tools:

**Style Tab**

[image]

**Computed Tab**

[image]

A flex container "blockifies" flex items, causing them to assume many qualities of block-level elements ([source](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#flex-items)).

But the `vertical-align` property applies only to inline-level and table-cell elements ([source](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS22/visudet.html#propdef-vert)).

That's why it doesn't work.

Regardless, `vertical-align`, even if it worked, is a totally unnecessary hack in this case. There are flex properties designed for aligning content in flex items.

```css
.container {
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  font-weight: 700;
  border: 1px solid #d9d9d9;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.item {
  flex: 1 1;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center; /* horizontal alignment, in this case */
  align-items: center;     /* vertical alignment, in this case */
  background-color: cyan;
}

.item:nth-of-type(2n) {
  background-color: aliceblue;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item">Hello</div>
  <div class="item">Hello</div>
  <div class="item">Hello</div>
  <div class="item">Hello</div>
</div>
```

Related posts:

- [How to vertically align text inside a flexbox?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25311541/3597276)
- [Setting ellipsis on text from a flex container](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45290956/3597276)

Comment: The question was changed. The long text wasn't in the original code. So this answer now covers the alignment part of the new question, but not the ellipsis part.

Answer (score 0):

> Blockquote ...`float`, `clear` and `vertical-align` have no effect on a flex item.
>   according to https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

See [How to vertically align text inside a flexbox?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25311541/how-to-vertically-align-text-inside-a-flexbox#answer-25311805) for a possible solution.

Answer (score 0):

You have to define those items also as flex containers, using the following CSS for them (no table-cell display...):

```
display: flex;
flex-direction: column;
justify-content: center;
```

```css
.container {
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  font-weight: 700;
  border: 1px solid #d9d9d9;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.item {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  flex: 1 1;
  background-color: cyan;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}

.item:nth-of-type(2n) {
  background-color: aliceblue;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item">Hello, I'm very very long string! Hello, I'm very very long string!</div>
  <div class="item">Hello</div>
  <div class="item">Hello</div>
  <div class="item">Hello</div>
</div>
```