# text-overflow:ellipsis not working on sass

Tags: reactjs, sass

I am working on a project and looks like the text-overflow: ellipsis not working in sass.

```css
.content
  background-color: green
  text-overflow: ellipsis
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
```

Here is the [link](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/BVXVEj) to the project

Comment: This is not a SASS problem, but a CSS problem. And also a problem of understanding how the property works to begin with ... so start by reading up on it, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-overflow

Answer (score 1):

It's working fine when you add all required rules. I modified your code.

```
.content
  background-color: green
  text-overflow: ellipsis
  white-space: nowrap
  overflow: hidden
```

[Here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-overflow) and [here](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_text-overflow.asp) you can read more about `text-overflow` property.

> Both of the following properties are required for text-overflow:
>
> - white-space: nowrap;
> - overflow: hidden;

[Link to altered Codepen](https://codepen.io/ajzk/pen/OEKoYr).

Comment: why is it one line only? Is it possible to populate the text till the same height of the picture? Here is an example https://www.themoviedb.org/movie

Comment: If you want to use multiline text with `text-overflow: ellipsis` you need to use JS. [Here you can read more about it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33058004/applying-an-ellipsis-to-multiline-text/33061059#33061059).