# How to give minimum 2 lines of space to overflowing text?

Tags: html, css, whitespace

Expected output should be at least 2 lines tall

[image]

I want to retain the `text-overflow: ellipsis` property

```html
<div style="min-height: 128px;
    border-radius: 7px;
    box-shadow: 0 2px 4px 0 rgba(210, 210, 210, 0.5);
    border: solid 0.3px rgba(26, 25, 25, 0.15);
    background-color: #ffffff;
    width: 268px;
    margin-bottom: 13px;">


  <div style="  width: 100px;     font-family: Roboto;
    font-size: 13px;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
    font-stretch: normal;
    line-height: normal;
    letter-spacing: 0.29px;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    padding-top: 5.6px;
    height: 49px;">
    Can we make this upper case? and also remove the word and’? Can we make this upper case? and also remove the word and’? Can we make this upper case? and also remove the word and’? Can we make this upper case? and also remove the word and’? Can we make
    this upper case? and also remove the word and’? Can we make this upper case? and also remove the word and’?

  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: I think either `padding-bottom: 2em` or `min-height: 2em` would help here.  Not sure I understand the question though.

Comment: If you run the snippet and compare it to the image above you will see the difference

Comment: At.  So, max 2 lines?  Probably `max-height: 2em` is where it's at then.

Comment: Where do i put it ?, doesnt work for me

Comment: I have removed my answer. A quick google search gave me this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33058004/applying-an-ellipsis-to-multiline-text

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got the best way using `-webkit-line-clamp` (doesn't work in IE) from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43186450/5724889)

```html
<div style="min-height: 128px;
    border-radius: 7px;
    box-shadow: 0 2px 4px 0 rgba(210, 210, 210, 0.5);
    border: solid 0.3px rgba(26, 25, 25, 0.15);
    background-color: #ffffff;
    width: 268px;
    margin-bottom: 13px;">


  <div style="       font-family: Roboto;
    font-size: 13px;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
    font-stretch: normal;
    line-height: normal;
    letter-spacing: 0.29px;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    padding-top: 5.6px;
    display: -webkit-box;
    -webkit-line-clamp: 2;
    -webkit-box-orient: vertical;">
    Can we make this upper case? and also remove the word and’? Can we make this upper case? and also remove the word and’? Can we make this upper case? and also remove the word and’? Can we make this upper case? and also remove the word and’? Can we make
    this upper case? and also remove the word and’? Can we make this upper case? and also remove the word and’?

  </div>

</div>
```