# Grid cell is expanding when using white-space

Tags: css, css-grid

I want the grid cell to fit as much text as possible until the text would not wrap on a second line.

I'm using the text ellipsis technique but it does not work when used in a grid.

In the codepen link below i was able to nowrap the text but it causes the cell grid to expand. Any idea why?

Additional I would to avoid any space between each column, that's why i want to avoid fix sizes.

Codepen: https://codepen.io/gregorym/pen/oNvVzqB?&editable=true

```html
<div id="container">
  <div>
    <span>Item as wide as the content, but at most 300 pixels. Item as wide as the content, but at most 300 pixels. Item as wide as the content, but at most 300 pixels. Item as wide as the content, but at most 300 pixels. Item as wide as the content, but at most 300 pixels. </span>
  </div>
  <div>
    Item with flexible width but a minimum of 200 pixels.
  </div>
  <div>
    Inflexible item of 150 pixels width.
  </div>
</div>
```

```css
#container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: minmax(min-content, auto) minmax(200px, 1fr) 150px;
  grid-gap: 5px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  height: 200px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #8cffa0;
  padding: 10px;
}

#container > div {
  background-color: #8ca0ff;
  padding: 5px;
}

#container > div > span {
  color: red;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

Comment: See this post for some general requirements for using ellipsis: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33061059/3597276

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> i was able to nowrap the text but it causes the cell grid to expand

1) Don't use `min-content` in `grid-template-columns` value. This expands the cell to fit the width of the content.

2) Properties that prohibit text wrapping and shorten the string, apply to `<div>`, not `<span>`

This is what you need?

### Result

```css
#container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: minmax(auto, 300px) minmax(200px, 1fr) 150px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  height: 200px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #8cffa0;
  padding: 10px;
}

#container div:nth-child(odd) {
  background: #EEE;
}

#container>div {
  background-color: #8ca0ff;
  padding: 5px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}

#container>div>span {
  color: red;
  /*   white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis; */
}
```

```html
<!-- Learn about this code on MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/minmax -->

<div id="container">
  <div>
    <span>Item as wide as the content, but at most 300 pixels. Item as wide as the content, but at most 300 pixels. Item as wide as the content, but at most 300 pixels. Item as wide as the content, but at most 300 pixels. Item as wide as the content, but at most 300 pixels. </span>
  </div>
  <div>
    Item with flexible width but a minimum of 200 pixels.
  </div>
  <div>
    Inflexible item of 150 pixels width.
  </div>
</div>
```

And same code on [CodePen](https://codepen.io/hisbvdis/pen/ZEzPBQW?editors=1100)

[image]