# Creating a thumbnail gallery with text below cropped and centered images

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create a simple thumbnail gallery with each image has a text below it. However, since the images I am dealing with have various sizes, I decided to crop and center each image in the gallery. I actually did this following the instructions given here:

https://jonathannicol.com/blog/2014/06/16/centre-crop-thumbnails-with-css/

However, texts of the images appear on the image. I could not find a way to move the text to the below. I tried adding padding to bottom but `padding-bottom` is not working. I suspect it is due to `height: auto` line. Somehow this setting preventing me to adjust padding in the vertical direction.

My html:

```
<div class="gallery">
    <img src="https://placehold.it/900x500" alt="">
    <div class="desc">My Text</div>
</div>
<div class="gallery">
    <img src="https://placehold.it/500x900" class="portrait" alt="">
    <div class="desc">My long long text</div>
</div>
```

Styling:

```
.gallery {
    position: relative;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin-top: 5vh;
    margin-right: 0.5vh;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    float: left;
}

.gallery img {
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    height: 100%;
    width: auto;
    -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.gallery img.portrait {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}

.desc {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 85%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    text-align: center;
}
```

jssfiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/8ue603on/

Thank you!

Comment: Hi try this solution if is ok for you https://jsfiddle.net/qj56L230/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think a better solution for you will be use object-fit for image
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/object-fit

```
.gallery img {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    object-fit: cover;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/csscoder/wymLkq16/3/

Answer (score 0):

1. Set a `max-height` to the images, it will look cleaner than setting `max-width`.
2. You should review all major aspects of CSS because then you would know about `object-fit` which you can experiment with at [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/object-fit).
3. If you have varying lengths of text you can't choose the number of characters short of messing with JavaScript though you won't need to. Put the text inside of a `span` element and set it to `display: block` so that you only have an `img` and `span` inside of the parent and the text appears below the image. You can [get an ellipsis](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33061059/606371) from overflowing text.
4. Never put text directly inside of a `div` - they are block level elements. Yes, you can technically get away with it though when you get to very high levels of skill you will find that have strict policies of how you work with code will greatly benefit and expedite your projects.