# text overflow make 2 text hidden (multi line ellipsis)

Tags: css, text

how to make my text like this in css

[image]

I tried this code :

```
height: 60px;
overflow: hidden;
white-space: nowrap;
text-overflow: ellipsis;
```

The result was like this

[image]

Please help me sir, thanks before

Comment: @Manjuboyz not work sir

Comment: then need code to validate, share the code.

Comment: white-space: nowrap; will keep all your text on one line, as you can see the name is ... which there is not enough width to display it

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Applying an ellipsis to multiline text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33058004/applying-an-ellipsis-to-multiline-text)