# Material ui can not text-overflow: ellipsis and overflow: hidden more than one line

Tags: javascript, node.js, material-ui, frontend, codesandbox

i am newbie for material ui, this is my current website state:
[reality of current website](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZmFzZ.jpg)

and this what i expected:
[what i expected it become](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fj3Zn.jpg)

as you can see from the those 2 pictures above, i want the text in the circle was shorten and truncate by 3 dots ... i tried typography of material ui with the property of nowrap but it truncated text from the very first line like this:
[nowrap typography](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2QP3l.jpg)

and i want it is truncated and ellipsised when text is too long and reached over 2 lines of the card, like the second image above, please help me out, thank you so much and have a good day :)

you can edit in the codesandbox demo in this link [codesandbox demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/card-text-overflow-7nsyr?file=/src/App.js)

Comment: I gave you a bad answer before; it's not easy as it seems. Have a look at this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33058004/applying-an-ellipsis-to-multiline-text

Comment: no worry, thank for taking your time to help me out, love your effort

Answer (score 1):

You could use `line-clamp`

```
mainContent: {
  display: 'box',
  lineClamp: 2,
  boxOrient: 'vertical',  
  overflow: 'hidden',
}
```

Codesandbox demo

[image: Edit card-text-overflow (forked)]

Comment: thank you, your code perfectly fit my criteria, i am sorry because of my hectic schedual until now i just have time to say thank for you, you have done so well