# How to limit number of lines in a pharagraph and add three dots (...) at the end of the text

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, text, material-ui

I want to limit the number of lines in a pharagraph... and i want to add three dots (...) at the end...

It should look like

```
Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing
and typesetting industry.Lorem Ipsum has been...
```

not like

```
Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing
and typesetting industry.Lor...
```

I was ablt to achive this last solution by adding a character count... like below

```
const getTrimmedText = (source: string) => {
    if (source.length > 100) {
        return source.substring(0, 100).trimEnd() + '...';
    } else {
        return source;
    }
};
```

but i want line count... Im using `MUI typhography` in `react`... so im somewhat limited... does anyone know how to achive this...

Comment: You can achieve this with just some simple CSS -> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/-webkit-line-clamp

Comment: example here -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33058004/applying-an-ellipsis-to-multiline-text

Comment: `-webkit-line-clamp` Browser compatibility on this is rather good.   I would think the W3C should drop the prefix on this one.