# Vertically Center a div using Flexbox

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I am trying to center a `div` vertically, using `flexbox`. I have `li's` with a height of `height:100px`. I then tried vertically centering it like this: `align-items: center`, and the top part gets cut off.

How can I vertically center something using `Flexbox` without the top part getting cut off?

Here's the [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6nmnzv8p/), and here's the code snippet:

```css
body,
html {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
#flexWrapper {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  background-color: aqua;
  height: 100%;
  align-items: center;
  /* This statement makes the problem */
  overflow: auto;
}
#flexContainer {
  width: 70%;
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  align-items: center;
  align-content: flex-start;
}
li {
  background-color: tomato;
  border: 1px solid black;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  flex-basis: calc(100%/3);
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div id="flexWrapper">
  <ul id="flexContainer">
    <li class="flex-item">1</li>
    <li class="flex-item">2</li>
    <li class="flex-item">3</li>
    <li class="flex-item">4</li>
    <li class="flex-item">5</li>
    <li class="flex-item">6</li>
    <li class="flex-item">7</li>
    <li class="flex-item">8</li>
    <li class="flex-item">9</li>
    <li class="flex-item">10</li>
    <li class="flex-item">11</li>
    <li class="flex-item">12</li>
    <li class="flex-item">13</li>
    <li class="flex-item">14</li>
    <li class="flex-item">15</li>
    <li class="flex-item">16</li>
    <li class="flex-item">17</li>
    <li class="flex-item">18</li>
    <li class="flex-item">19</li>
    <li class="flex-item">20</li>
    <li class="flex-item">21</li>
    <li class="flex-item">22</li>
    <li class="flex-item">23</li>
    <li class="flex-item">24</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: I believe I found a simple solution see my answer.

Comment: In addition to `align-items` and `justify-content` for centering flex items, there is a second flex method: `auto` margins. In cases where the flex item to be vertically centered overflows the flex container, the second method may be more useful. See [@Oriol's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32672661/3597276) in the duplicate reference for more details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nothing is wrong with your Flex-Fu, it's what's outside of your flexboxes that are giving you undesirable results. Take a look at the Fiddle and/or snippet below:

**[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zer00ne/muouy9j7/)**

```css
html {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font: 400 16px/1.5 'Source Code Pro';
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
}
*,
*:before,
*:after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0 solid transparent;
}
#flexWrapper {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  background-color: aqua;
  height: 100%;
  align-items: center;
  /* This statement makes the problem */
  overflow: auto;
}
#flexContainer {
  width: 70%;
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  align-items: center;
  align-content: flex-start;
}
li {
  background-color: tomato;
  border: 1px solid black;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  flex-basis: calc(100%/3);
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div id="flexWrapper">
  <ul id="flexContainer">
    <li class="flex-item">1</li>
    <li class="flex-item">2</li>
    <li class="flex-item">3</li>
    <li class="flex-item">4</li>
    <li class="flex-item">5</li>
    <li class="flex-item">6</li>
    <li class="flex-item">7</li>
    <li class="flex-item">8</li>
    <li class="flex-item">9</li>
    <li class="flex-item">10</li>
    <li class="flex-item">11</li>
    <li class="flex-item">12</li>
    <li class="flex-item">13</li>
    <li class="flex-item">14</li>
    <li class="flex-item">15</li>
    <li class="flex-item">16</li>
    <li class="flex-item">17</li>
    <li class="flex-item">18</li>
    <li class="flex-item">19</li>
    <li class="flex-item">20</li>
    <li class="flex-item">21</li>
    <li class="flex-item">22</li>
    <li class="flex-item">23</li>
    <li class="flex-item">24</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

**Relevant Code**

```
html {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font: 400 16px/1.5 'Source Code Pro';
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100vw;
}
*, *:before, *:after {
    box-sizing: inherit;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0 solid transparent;
}
```

I reset the CSS **✲** then applied `height: 100vh` and `width: 100vw` to `<html>` so that every inch of your layout is viewable--no unsightly cutoff. Further details on `vh` and `vw` can found [here](http://thenewcode.com/660/Using-vw-and-vh-Measurements-In-Modern-Site-Design).

**✲** All CSS reset rulsets are optional, the only properties required to succeed are `vh` and `vw`.

Comment: Resetting every elements margin and padding to zero feels a bit over the edge.

Comment: I just use reset in demos because it eliminates defaults and UA rulesets that would normally take me time debugging. I prefer dealing with a minimal environment and finding a solution rather than fumble around with browser foibles and ridiculous defaults. The CSS resets are optional and not critical to the solution's function. I will update my answer to clarify the key properties..

Answer (score -1):

Is this one acceptable?

```
#flexWrapper {

justify-content: center;
background-color: aqua;
height: 100%;
width:70%;
margin:0 auto;
}
```

http://codepen.io/damianocel/pen/gavEzv

To have it responsive you will have to use % values instead of px.

Really depends how you want the layout to look, always 3 rows and 8 columns?

Comment: In the link you posted, it shows it in columns, not in rows. Also, can you edit the JSFiddle, not codepen? I personally like JSFiddle better. :) Thanks!

Comment: Ok i'll do it as rows and in JSFiddle:-)
So, that layout is fine, as long its rows?

Comment: I want 3 rows, (I will be changing it later on, so I still need the flexibility)

Comment: @Jessica
here you go:
http://jsfiddle.net/6nmnzv8p/2/
For 3 rows, just make sure to have the width of the container set at exactly the width of 3 li. Then you can add more li vertically.

Comment: Thanks! When you just have 4 `li's` then it isn't vertically centered anymore. http://jsfiddle.net/6nmnzv8p/3/

Comment: NP:-) See, that is why i have done it as column layout first:-)
Just to be sure, the 4th li, where do you want it to be displayed?

Comment: @Jessica
http://jsfiddle.net/6nmnzv8p/3/ :-)

Comment: I think you may have sent the wrong link. It's the same as the previous one.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/6nmnzv8p/4/
Sorry, bit unfamiliar with JSF.

Comment: No worries! It isn't centered vertically.